# DPI for picture sizing in Android

Tags: android, image, dpi, image-size, density-independent-pixel

If I have a "picture.png" which is 100px - 100px 72dpi (dot per inch) and is set in the drawable folder, if I want to supply a "picture.png" for HighDensity (hdpi) is it enough I change in photoshop the size in 150px - 150px keeping 72dpi or do I have to double the 72dpix2=144dpi?

As far I have made for hdpi 480x800px at 300dpi and 1280x800px at 320dpi but it also increase the file size more.

Comment: refer this link you sill get your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930031/how-do-i-convert-ppi-into-dpi-for-android-images