# Full screen Alternative drawables

Tags: android, image, resources, drawable, resolution

At http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html I can read:

> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you
>   should follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four generalized
>   densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48
>   pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all
>   the different sizes should be:
>
> 36x36 for low-density 48x48 for medium-density 72x72 for high-density
>   96x96 for extra high-density

1. I guess all the units above are in pixels?
2. When I am creating an image in photoshop, I should not only specify the dimension (like 36x36 pixels), I should also specify a resolution. How do I know which resolution I should specify in these cases.
3. If I want to create a full screen drawable, which dimensions and resolutions should I use for the diferent densities?
4. I have a tablet and I have tested that it picks resources from the mdpi folder. I guess the best strategy is to create drawable in this directory and adjust there size so it looks nice. I can from there use the scaling 3:4:6:8 o create the other resources?

---

ok, I have found the answers here: 
[How do I convert ppi into dpi for Android images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930031/how-do-i-convert-ppi-into-dpi-for-android-images)

1. yes
2. The resolution in ps is only for printing
3. See link above
4. to be tested...

Answer (score 0):

I agree partly with your comment above..

for third question dimensions depend much more on target screen size not on resolution. For example: 1st screen can be HDPI with dimensions 480x800 and 2nd HDPI as well but 480x854. In that case HDPI doesn't play the main role, no?

forth question: it can be useful to check occasionally [dashboard statistic page on used Android devices](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) provided by Google Dev web page. That can help u to focus providing graphics which look nice on most used devices. It can be used to focus target android version as well.

beside this things it can be useful to have some UI elements as [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images, so they are not deformed on different screen ratios.

Cheers, enjoy Android wonderland. ;)