# How to get correct width and hight for android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, screen

After reading the following:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

[How do I convert ppi into dpi for Android images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930031/how-do-i-convert-ppi-into-dpi-for-android-images)

I assumed that "dp = px / (dpi / 160)". I tested it on the LDPI screen and it worked perfectly, my first thought was "finally, a breakthrough!", but then after testing it on a HDPI screen I found it did not work so well. So then I tried "dp = px * (dpi / 160)" and found that didn't work, not that I figured it would... I tried a couple other formulas, but none of them worked. One of them was to only use the dp on the small screens and then just get the screen px for the other screens. That didn't work.

Obviously after reading how to support multiple screens I am suppose to use DP to get the correct width and height to work with. I am not quite sure why this is failing so that I why I turned to you.

Here is my code:

```
public class Scale {

    ScreenType type;
    Display display;

    public Scale(WindowManager wm) {
        this.display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        // Get Display Type //
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int density = metrics.densityDpi;
        switch(density) {
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                this.type = ScreenType.LDPI;
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                this.type = ScreenType.MDPI;
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                this.type = ScreenType.HDPI;
                break;
            default:
                this.type = ScreenType.XHDPI;
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    public ScreenType getScreenType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return this.display.getWidth();
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.display.getHeight();
    }

    public int getDPWidth() {
        float dp = this.getWidth() / (this.getScreenType().getDensity() / 160f);
        return (int) dp;
    }

    public int getDPHeight() {
        float dp = this.getHeight() / (this.getScreenType().getDensity() / 160f);
        return (int) dp;
    }

}
```

ScreenType enum is as follows:

```
public enum ScreenType {
    LDPI(120), MDPI(160), HDPI(240), XHDPI(320);

    private final int density;
    ScreenType(int density) {
        this.density = density;
    }

    public int getDensity() {
        return this.density;
    }
}
```

I know I don't need the ScreenType enum, but not talking about this at the moment. Just need to figure out why the screen is always get the wrong size.

Now when I go to draw the background I do the following...

```
batcher.beginBatch(Assets.loadingAtlas);
for(int x = 0; x <= this.scale.getDPWidth(); x += 50) {
    for(int y = 0; y <= this.scale.getDPHeight(); y += 50) {
        batcher.drawSprite(x, y, 50, 50, Assets.backgroundPattern);
    }
}
batcher.endBatch();
```

Then it goes to the batcher which has the following code...

```
public void beginBatch(Texture texture) {
    texture.bind();
    numSprites = 0;
    bufferIndex = 0;
}

public void drawSprite(float x, float y, float width, float height, TextureRegion region) {
    float halfWidth = width / 2;
    float halfHeight = height / 2;
    float x1 = x - halfWidth;
    float y1 = y - halfHeight;
    float x2 = x + halfWidth;
    float y2 = y + halfHeight;

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

    numSprites++;
}

public void endBatch() {
    vertices.setVertices(verticesBuffer, 0, bufferIndex);
    vertices.bind();
    vertices.draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numSprites * 6);
    vertices.unbind();
}
```

Then when you draw the vertices the following code is used...

```
public void draw(int primitiveType, int offset, int numVertices) {        
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();

    if(indices!=null) {
        indices.position(offset);
        gl.glDrawElements(primitiveType, numVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
    } else {
        gl.glDrawArrays(primitiveType, offset, numVertices);
    }        
}
```

**Now my two biggest questions are this**: One, am I using the correct formula to calculate where I should draw and for how many times I should draw the background? Two, should I have a formula for when I draw the element to put dp back to pixels?

What happens when I fail is the following:

[image: Background_HDPI_SCREEN.png]

**The yellow marks where it ok to have black and the blue X's mark where it is not ok to have black. The blue should extend much further than it is.**

I understand mathematically why this is happening, but feel like there could be a better formula that would work for both LDPI and HDPI screens rather than just LDPI. This formula also makes it a tiny bit smaller on MDPI.

The math is Density-Independent Pixels (DP) = WIDTH / (DENSITY / 160). So an example would be DP = 800/(240/160) = 800/1.5 = 533

So what are your thoughts?

Thanks ahead of time for any input! If you want an SSCCE let me know, but it would take some time to make for this instance and I am hopping we won't need to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to know DP/density for drawing with OpenGL? The Renderer class has a onSurfaceChanged method that gives you the width and height in pixels at initialization time. Maybe that's enough for you?

Comment: "You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities." - developer.android _ I thought that would mean I need to use DP for making sure that I got the correct width and height I was suppose to use. However that might do the trick, my question is when is this method called by open gl? Does it call it when the application is started?

Comment: `onSurfaceChanged` is called every time the view is resized (or initialized). It's a method of `Renderer` that you can override. DP is nice to know if you want a uniform look on all devices, but if all you want is the screen dimensions you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to support all screen sizes. Hence the tags "screen" "multiple" "support". The onSurfaceChanged() method gives me the same results as the getWidth() and getHeight() methods I use from the display. I keep finding that this comes a tad short of what I need and am confused on why this is. It is usually just a couple pixels off from drawing it and if I just add like 51 pixels to the width and height opengl-es hits the rest of the screen with the background I want. Is there something wrong with my for loops? If so, that would make things make a lot more sense.

Comment: There was something wrong with my for loop, after changing my for loop to be "for(int x = 0; x <= this.scale.getHeight() + 50; x += 50)" it now completes the whole screen. The problem was that I did not have the loop covering the last part, which I knew. It was not until I saw the Log.d that said "X: 850/800  Y:500/480 - Width: 50  Height: 50" That I saw I actually needed to go over like this. My loop detected that it was 30px's over and stooped. I needed to add another 50 because of the image size. After that I was fine.

Comment: On another note, I think you are right. I don't need DP for placing the images on the screen. Rather for when I create the images. Thanks again!