# Android. xhdpi folder

Tags: android, screen, dpi

So, you can add 3 types of images inside individual folders, `drawable-ldpi, -mdpi and -hdpi`, from which Android picks the proper image depending on each specific device.

My question is, what about xhdpi? The large screens out there. I'm guessing they will use the hdpi, but if i'd like to add another larger image for those screens, should i add another folder inside the "res" directory, named drawable-xhdpi? Will Android know to pick the image from this folder?

Or how is it done in case of xhdpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,Android know to pick the image from this folder.drawable-xhdpi folder is generally for extra large image or high resolution image. For more information check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Also, regarding this guy's response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930031/how-do-i-convert-ppi-into-dpi-for-android-images So if i place images with minimum dimensions inside each folder, it will work properly for any screen size? For example if i put a 470x320px image in mdpi folder, but the screen is 640x480 (or something like that), will it rescale the 470x320 to that size? I'm kinda confused :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create folder in **res** directory named

**drawable-xhdpi**

and keep extra large images in this folder. Android will pick images for large screens