# How can I provide Bitmaps for the full Android screen resolution?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, resolution, pixel

Simple question actually and I have spent hours searching for an answer.

What is the best way to provide bitmap resources that fill the full screen? For instance for a full app background or something.

Currently I place all my images in drawable-nodpi in a medium resolution and obviously need a lot of custom scaling. I do need images the fill the full, or the half or a third of the screen width. What is the best way?

Michael Ellen states ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/6938345/1162415 ) that e.g. drawable-ldpi has 240 px screen width. While I would love this to be true I do not think so. Table 3 at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing clearly says that ldpi might result in actual px resoluation width of 240, 480 or 600.

Should I build the app with drawable-*dpi fixed for screen sizes, something like drawable-ldpi-small and so on? We do make use of 78 cards ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinkwerther.tarot if you are interested) which should be displayed almost full screen. That makes a hell of an overall app size. Either that or a hell of a lot of different apk files.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is one solution I am currently thinking of that might be suitable. Namely to provide kind of low resolution default images and have the apk with an expansion file ( http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html ) of really high resolution images which get scaled and stored on first use. Before I dive into this possibility I just want to make sure there is no simpler solution... So please feel free to hint me to the hidden places I happen not to be aware of!