# Android. ldpi, mdpi, hdpi clarification

Tags: android

So, in regards to this stackoverflow accepted answer: [How do I convert ppi into dpi for Android images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930031/how-do-i-convert-ppi-into-dpi-for-android-images)

So, ok, i make each background image the dimensions that that guy specifies in the answer. 
BUT, if i define the other ImageViews (smaller ones), that are placed on the screen, in relation to the sizes defined above (e.g. let's say an ImageView has dimensions 20x20 for the hdpi devices, if i calculate this dimensions for the ldpi devices, the image would have to be 7x7 pixels, which is terribly small) then the ldpi devices won't be able to see anything on the screen :) Or will they? Am i doing it right, or not?

I'm terribly confused. Can someone clarify this for me please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images should be at least the size which can be easily viewable, or even clickable for the user on his/her devices.

The guidelines are for specific images, like launcher icons, or menu items, and not necessarily for any images you use in your app. For these kind of images, you are the best judge of specifying the image sizes and resolutions.

You could well have those images as only mdpi, and supply an hdpi version, so that it atleast has a higher resolution image for hdpi and xdpi devices.

Comment: So you're saying i should only place mdpi and hdpi images and ignore the rest? But, won't the xhdpi devices stretch the hdpi images? Won't that look a little off?

Comment: Yeah. Ignore only if you are satisfied what you achieve with it. I mean, check for xhdpi, if it looks good, and you don't want to improve it further, ignore that.

Comment: I've just tried placing only mdpi size and hdpi sized iamges in the two folders. But the problem is that when i load the app onto an ldpi device, it uses the hdpi images, instead of the mdpi. SHouldn't it choose the mdpi, so it has "less to rescale"? :)

Comment: Yeah, it should. Are you sure, it picks up the hdpi one?

Comment: Yes. I wrote mdpi on all the other ones so i can differentiate them :))

Comment: Hmm, Strange. I have seen it work correctly. It does pick up mdpi images. Try cleaning your project once, and make sure you are using a ldpi emulator.

Comment: Ok. well, thanks for your help. I'll get to the bottom of this somehow. If you say it should work, then it should :) It must be something on my end.

Comment: UH, I've just copied the images from the mdpi folder inside the ldpi one. It works now. But it's kinda redundant :(

Answer (score 2):

The resolutions mentioned in the other question will always fill the screen, but you should provide different layout files for each screen size to stay dpi independent (if you so wish).

Look at the example from the dev page [image: http://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/density-test-good.png]

Also, it always helps to fire up the appropriate simulator (middle size with mdpi, smallest size with ldpi and biggest size with hdpi, depending on what devices you are planning to support) and try your layouts out.