# PPI PIXEL DENSITY new confuse

Tags: android, android-layout

I found out that my created app design is not properly working on samsung galaxy note. I search about the phones specs and fount out this part

```
~285 ppi pixel density
```

What is it? ahm is DPI and PPI are the same? Cause in android there is no 285DPI.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as marketing materials and tech-sheets are concerned (which I assume is what you're looking at) then they are the same.

PPI = Pixels per inch. A measure of how many pixels lie along a line parallel or perpendicular to the display (i.e. not diagonally).

DPI = Dots per inch. A term used in printing (where are images are made of dots rather than pixels) but carried over to screen terminology.

PPI is the preferred term but they are used interchangeably.

The Android OS supports arbitrary resolutions (note that "resolution" really refers to the DPI of a display rather than the display area's pixel dimensions), so if a display is 285dpi it doesn't necessarily mean that the system (or the applications running on it) draw a 285px-long line and expect it to be 1 inch in real-life, there will be variations. 285dpi is close enough to Android's "HDPI" mode of 240dpi.

You can read more here: [How do I convert ppi into dpi for Android images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930031/how-do-i-convert-ppi-into-dpi-for-android-images)