# Android screen size resolution aspect ratio

Tags: android, drawable, resolution, aspect-ratio, screen-size

I am almost done with my first app, not anything awesome. But my problem is that i have only used the hdpi drawable folder. I have made it fit the screen resolution 480x800 which is 3:5 aspect ratio. It works in all sizes in 3:5 aspect ratio. But ehn i for example the the screen resolution to Samsung Galaxy S3 size 720x1280 which is 9:16 aspect ratio all the buttons is too small and in the wrong place! What do i need to do?

NOTE: It is not a problem to change screen size, but it is a problem to change screen aspect ratio!

Do I need to make images in all four drawable folders? In that case, what size should I make the different images in the different folders if I already have 480x800 in hdpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the 3:4:6:8 when creating image sizes to support multiple screens. To support all screen sizes you should use all of the four folders.

You may also want to look at the answer to this question, it's very helpful: [How do I convert ppi into dpi for Android images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930031/how-do-i-convert-ppi-into-dpi-for-android-images)