# How to tell the difference between dpis on tablet and phone?

Tags: android, dpi

I know that obviously a tablet has a higher screen resolution than a phone because it has more pixels(dots on the screen) From what ive been reading, tablets also have a higher dpi(dots per inch) than phones as well. How can you tell that one screen has a higher dots per inch than another screen? If i launch angry birds on both screens, they look pretty much identical. I know for resolution - bigger screen - more dots

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930031/how-do-i-convert-ppi-into-dpi-for-android-images?rq=1

Comment: yeah i get the conversion stuff. But like what im asking is if you take a look at two screens, how can you tell if one screen has a higher dpi than another screen? Like for resolution, you can tell by size(greater size = more dots)

Comment: can't really, unless you put up a contrived picture of a thin angled white line on a black background and look closely at the aliasing.

Comment: Like i just dont understand why a tablet would have a higher dip than a phone

Comment: why not? My nexus 10 table is 2560x1440 on a 10" screen. We've got a PC at work with a 30" screen that's also 2560x1440. it's an arms race like anything else in the mobile space. "We've got a bigger screen" "We've got more pixels" "We've got more useless crap that sucks battery life, except we also have a bigger battery!"

Comment: Because there are more physical pixels per inch, simple as that. Angry birds (as you have started that example) is just developing in a way that the different DPI-Values don't matter. Or in other words, they don't define their objects on a pixel-basis but on a dpi-basis.

Comment: How does higher dip change up an image for say, does it make it more clear?

Comment: Yes, if you have two devices, 1 with high dip and one with low dip but same dimensions (in inch) and you have the image full-screen, then it makes the image clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 causes why DPI differs. You must be aware of both the causes.

1) **Physically** more dots per inch: Better technology of the screen.

Example: Screen is 2" wide and it has 500 dots, so per 1" it is 250 dots (=**250 dpi**)
Another screen is 10" wide and it has also 500 dots, so per 1" it is 50 dots (=**50 dpi**)

2) **Virtually**: physically same technology of the screen *(see point 1: technology of screen)*, but different resampling.

Remember when you set up the PC desktop resolution. You have the same screen, but you can set different resolution (view quality), so in this case **you can set dots per inch up to maximum of the screen allows** *(see point 1: technology of screen)*.